# Rails Rendering namespaced template based on version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I am trying to render a specific view path based on the version of my design (stored as a db column).

The idea is if the version of my design is 1, I will render

products/v1/show.html.erb

if 2 :

products/v2/show.html.erb

To achieve this I have tried in ProductsController :

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_view_paths
  def set_view_paths
    prepend_view_path Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'products', "v#{current_tenant.ui_version}")
  end
end
```

and nesting my show template `in v1/show.html.erb`.

However now that I've moved the show template, I get `ProductsController#show is missing a template for request formats: text/html`

Am I missing something about `prepend_view_path` method ?

Answer (score 0):

### Clarification about `preprend_view_path`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/ViewPaths/ClassMethods.html

Before to had something to it, you can look at the current array.
It should contain `app/views`.

Then your `ProductsController#show` will look within it for `products/show`

I guess you get a bit confused here.

If you use:
`prepend_view_path Rails.root.join('app', 'views', "v#{current_tenant.ui_version}")`
Then your product folder will look like this:

```
app/views
  v1/products/show
  v2/products/show
```

`prepend_view_path` has a more global impact.

### Live split versions in `product` folder

If you want:

```
app/views/products
  v1/show
  v2/show
```

You can override the render method:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  # actions ..

  private

  def render(*args)
    change_some_args_here = "/#{design_version_name}/#{params[:action]}"
    super(*args)
  end

  def design_version_name
    # implement me
  end
end
```

#### EDIT: now this concept is native with `variants` option

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#the-variants-option

### Changing controller view path

There is also the `controller_path` class method

```
def self.controller_path
  "products/v1"
end
```

However as you can see, `v1` is static here.
Class-method means you don't know about the "live" context ...

### Conclusion

I guess the second method is what match your need.
EDIT: the `variants` option looks like the direct answer to your question.